# How do I legally run multiple instances of Office on a computer with Server 2008 R2

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I have several people who need to work concurrently on a computer in my home office from remote locations.  I have found that Windows Server 2008 R2 will allow multiple user sessions but I have not been able to figure out how to provide them **legal** access to Excel.  I don't mind buying multiple licenses but I can't seem to understand how they could be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/e09ee781-82c2-4399-85f4-1b90ae690ccb) answers the question.
Basically you need to license the server as a terminal services server, and then license office through the volume license program for the correct number of users.

Comment: Thanks I had seen this but did not understand its relevance I get it now.

Comment: I wouldn't worry, understanding MS Licensing is an entire course to itself!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Office365](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/)?  It allows you to run Office Apps over the web.

From MS website:

> Access and share from anywhere with anyone
>
> - View and edit Office
>     documents on your devices, anywhere you go.
> - Work with others across
>     platforms, devices, and Office versions to write papers, prepare
>     presentations, create spreadsheets, and take notes.
> - Store documents on
>     the web so you can share them with anyone who has a supported browser,
>     even if they don't have Office installed.